# QT 5 XCB not able to connect to display

Tags: linux, paraview, openfoam

I am on windows 11 using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS in Wsl. I have openFOAM installed and built aswell as paraview.  Whenever I go to launch paraview in openFOAM I get this error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0.0
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-username'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Maybe I need to set a different display?  However, after several google attemps I have yet to find the command for that.

Thanks!

Comment: Using wsl is not officially supported, some workaround are described [here](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/build-paraview-inside-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/6439/15) using VcXsrv to configure X server. Someone also report there that installing from `anaconda` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Find the local IP address of your **Windows** machine by following these [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-ip-address-in-windows-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9). you can also use the command line prompt:  Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the command line prompt, type `ipconfig`.
- For example, let's assume that after following the previous step you've found the local IP address to be `192.168.1.55`
- In **WSL**, run the following commands (replace the IP address with your own):

  ```
  export DISPLAY="192.168.1.55:0"
  paraview
  ```
- If Paraview runs correctly, add the export command to your `~/.bashrc` to make that change permanent:

  ```
  echo 'export DISPLAY="192.168.1.55:0"' >> ~/.bashrc
  ```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that,  It thinks for a moment longer than returns:  

qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display ***.***.*.***:0
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-username'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @jkballuh23: Does that happen with other GUI programs or only with paraview?

Comment: @jkballuh23: You can also diagnose your system following the official instructions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/wiki/Diagnosing-%22cannot-open-display%22-type-issues-with-WSLg)

Answer (score 0):

Follow s.ouchene's comment, and open the XLaunch, it works.

Download the VcXsrv installer.
(if the above link does not work, go to the VcXsrv files page and download the latest vcxsrv-64.X.X.X.X.installer.exe file).
Run XLaunch that was installed by VcXsrv.
Open the “Extra settings” window and: a) Deselect (uncheck) “Native opengl”; b) Select “Disable access control”.